# Display Array Data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, arraylist

I'm getting these array from backend

```
{_id: "6006a53cfc8d582e88f26bda",…}
address: "194/24,Magalegoda,Veyangoda"
mobile: "+94774335548"
name: "Gayath Sandarge"
orders: [{_id: "6006a511fc8d582e88f26bd8", product_name: "highland fresh milk", product_brand: "Highland",…},…]
0: {_id: "6006a511fc8d582e88f26bd8", product_name: "highland fresh milk", product_brand: "Highland",…}
product_brand: "Highland"
product_category: "fresh milk"
product_name: "highland fresh milk"
product_price: "100"
quantity: "3"
_id: "6006a511fc8d582e88f26bd8"
1: {_id: "6006a519fc8d582e88f26bd9", product_name: "fbndxcfn", product_brand: "fdncn",…}
product_brand: "fdncn"
product_category: "fgncfggn"
product_name: "fbndxcfn"
product_price: "464"
quantity: "4"
token: 
_id: "6006a519fc8d582e88f26bd9"
```

my front end code is

> const ListBar = (props) => {
> return (

```
    <div className='product-card container'>
    
  <div>
  <p className='product-card label'>{props.product.name}</p>
  <p className='product-card label'>{props.product.address}</p>
  <p className='product-card label'>{props.product.mobile}</p>
  <ul>
  <li className='product-card label'>{props.product.orders[]}</li>
  <li className='product-card label'>{props.product.orders[]}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
);
```

}

const Store = () => {
const [listData, setListData] = useState({ lists: []});

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios(
            'http://localhost:4000/store/admin/orders'
        );
        setListData({ lists: result.data });
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

return (
    <div className="store">
    <div class="header">
      <a href="/store" class="logo">Milk.Lk</a>
      <div className="menu">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/freshmilk">FreshMilk</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/login">Contact us</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a href="/register">SingUp</a>
        <a href="/login">Login</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">    
    <div class="cards">
           
    {listData.lists.map((current, i) => (
                    <ListBar product={current} key={i} />
                ))}
                
                
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
);
```

}

export default Store;

can i get some help to get orders array details with other details.name,address and mobile is display correctly but details cant print

Comment: <li className='product-card label'>{props.product.orders[]}</li>
  <li className='product-card label'>{props.product.orders[]}</li> Pass the index you need into the brackets, the orders is an array that needs to be mapped through. If you dont know the index, then you will have to target it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to render array data from orders into a single li. Each order object needs to be mapped seperately.

Example:

```js
const ListBar = (props) => { 

return (
  <div className='product-card container'>
  <div>
  <p className='product-card label'>{props.product.name}</p>
  <p className='product-card label'>{props.product.address}</p>
  <p className='product-card label'>{props.product.mobile}</p>
  <ul>{props.product.orders.map((order, i) => {
  return <li>{order.product_name}</li>
  })}</ul>
  </div>
   </div>
    
    
);
}
```